# How can I adduce the mathematical model in my master thesis?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, neural-networks

Please explain how to adduce and describe the mathematical model obtained by neural network modeling, if the model contains 50 inputs and five neurons in the hidden layer. How to show values of weights and biases in the formula if i used the tangent hyperbolic function for all neurons?

[This is how i did it and i guess it's totally false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnK1U.jpg)

Comment: This might be better asked on stats.stackexchange or computer science, but I will let others voice their opinions on this.

Answer (score 0):

No one (not even your advisors, this is the sad truth) will ever read these values. Only you, while trying empirically to adapt your network to the context. I'd rather put a nice nice representation of your neural network, explain why I chose the tangent hyperbolic function, and some stats on the weights. My advice : put everything in excel and calculate stuff until you have an interesting correlation. You can also check numerically a theorem, but to my knowledge there are really few on neural networks.